# I want to analysis with classification algoritms using BERT's hidden state

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm using the [Huggingface Transformer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/index.html) package and BERT with PyTorch. 
I try to do text classification with  [CamembertForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/models/camembert/modeling_camembert.html#CamembertForSequenceClassification).
I can get the result, but I want to challenge more difficult task.

I refer to this [literature](https://aclanthology.org/2021.woah-1.13.pdf). In section 4.1 of this document, it is stated that

> After training, we drop the softmax activation layer and use BERT's hidden state as the feature vector, which we then use as input for different classification algorithms.

So, I check the [modeling_bert.py](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.html). There is 
`attention_probs = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)(attention_scores)`
If I look at it as per the paper, does it mean to use the **attention_scores** before passing it through Softmax function? If so, how can I use the **attention_scores** and apply it to the classification algorithm?
In short, what I want to do is to use the hidden state of BERT and apply it to Logistic Regression and so on.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They did not mean that Softmax layer, because that one is inside BertAttention. They meant the pooler layer on top of BERT.

I found their repository provided in the paper: https://github.com/axenov/politik-news

It seems when they train, they use the plain BertForSequenceClassification. (Which uses hidden_states -> pooler activation -> linear classifier -> loss)

When they predict, they only use the hidden_states (or in bert_modeling.py it's called sequence_output), then they pass it to a different classifier loaded in [BiasPredictor.py:L26](https://github.com/axenov/politik-news/blob/master/BiasPredictor.py#L26).

So if you want to try a different classifier, use it [here](https://github.com/axenov/politik-news/blob/master/BiasPredictor.py#L129).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Thanks to you, I now understand about Softmax. I would like to use modeling_bert.py, but if so, does it mean that I just pass the obtained sequence_output through Logistic Regression or something?

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes, use the sequence_output as input features to your desired classifier. However, you should train it first. They do that in "BERT_baseline.ipynb"